# How to use activity on result?

Tags: android

```
            String s1 = e1.getText().toString();
            String s2 = e2.getText().toString();
            String s3 = e3.getText().toString();

            Intent updateIntent = new Intent(DetailActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name", s1);
            bundle.putString("lat", s2);
            bundle.putString("lon", s3);

            updateIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

this is my first class where I put the datas. I sended data the second class that i will use soon to first class that i am using in codes. Now I must use these bundle datas in my first class again. There is an ArrayList item that i put datas from JSON. I must change these data on my first class again. I hope that I explain my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To use activity for result you should **first start** it in your first class:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

in **second class** you need to set result and finish the activity:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String msg = i.getStringExtra("color");
if (msg.contentEquals("choosecolor")) 
{
    i.putExtra("chosencolor", color);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}
```

and in the **first class** you can receive the data using this code:

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         //get the data sent from the second class here...
         data = data.getStringExtra("key");
         //do something with my precious data
     }
 }
```